# Authentication or permission failure for some hosts in inventory

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a inventory with around 10 hosts and my playbook runs on all except 2. I am able to login to those 2 hosts passwordlessly from Ansible Server. But when I run the playbook or even a simple ping module I get error:

```
192.168.x.xxx | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the remote directory. Consider changing the remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1498895076.45-202255130489130 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1498895076.45-202255130489130=\"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1498895076.45-202255130489130 `\" ), exited with result 1",
"unreachable": true
}
```

I have already tried changing the a`nsible.cfg` for `remote_dir`, changed connection type as suggested in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5725

The verbose mode output is:

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/__init__.pyc
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/ping.py
<192.168.x.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
 Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/ping.py
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-C)(-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
 <192.168.x.xxx> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/home/webtech/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<192.168.x.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/webtech/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.x.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1498903623.28-136703981609211 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1498903623.28-136703981609211="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1498903623.28-136703981609211 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Nothing helped. 
Please help me, how can I run my playbook in those 2 hosts?

Comment: I also referred to other stackoverflow threads but no solution works for me

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to help you, given the information you provided. If a host declines connection with a permission failure, it simply means you have no permissions to access it and there is an SSH configuration error (it's not a topic  for StackOverflow, btw). At least please provide the vital information when running with `-vvvv`.

Comment: @Niceha, from verbose mode output you should be able to reproduce the issue with only SSH, without Ansible. That should narrow it down.

Comment: From that output you can extract a test command like this, for example: `ssh -vvv <your_host> -i <your_keyfile> '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "\` echo $HOME/test \`" && echo test="\` echo $HOME/test \`" ) && sleep 0'"'"''`

Comment: This would run SSH against your problem server passing in a command that creates a simple dir named `test` under your `$HOME`, the same way Ansible handles its remote_dir. If this SSH command works, then the problem could be in other SSH flags or inconsistent configuration on those two servers. Either way, it should give a direction to dig in

Comment: @Tony: Thanks a lot, the issue was with shell.

Answer (score -1):

ansible <> 
add -s at the end to run it as sudo user

Comment: The issue isnt about user, this is running on all other hosts which use same OS initialization image. So is there anything else which can help?

Comment: There are so many unanswered/unaccepted answers on SO regarding this problem with Ansible. This is so annoying.